# Merge [fec] and [channelcoding] tags?

Tags: discussion

I propose merging these two tags, since they are essentially synonymous. I'd prefer to keep [channelcoding], since it's more descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MBaz, can do!  Could you please take some time to edit the wiki associated with <kbd>channelcoding</kbd> so that it's clear that <kbd>fec</kbd> fits there?

---

OK, those are now merged so that <kbd>fec</kbd> is now a synonym of <kbd>channelcoding</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the tag wiki; it's awaiting review.

Comment: @MBaz OK, thank-you! I've approved both edits.